# Simple statement on number theory

Tags: number-theory

Say $k$ is an odd natural number and $n$ is a positive natural number and also say that $2^{n+2}$ $|$ $(k^{2^n}-1)(k^{2^n}+1)$. We are also aware of the fact the $k^{2^n}+1$ is not divisible by $2^{n+2}$. Can we deduce that $2^{n+2}$ $|$ $k^{2^n}-1$? This statement was used on a proof i saw, but can't prove it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is worded somewhat strangely, but it is true that $2^{n+2}\,|\,k^{2^n}-1$ (using your restrictions on $n,k$)  This is because the multiplicative group of units $\pmod {2^{n+2}}$ is not cyclic for $n≥1$ (see, e.g. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n)).  Thus every odd $k$ has order $2^m\pmod {2^{n+2}}$ where $m≤n$.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment:

**(*)If $2^{n+3}|(k^{2^n}-1)(k^{2^n}+1)$** the answer is obviously yes: $(k^{2^n}-1), (k^{2^n}+1)$ are two consecutive even numbers, one has to be divisible by $2$ but not divisible by $4$. Therefore the other is divisible by $2^{n+2}$.

**(**)If there exists some $k,n$ such that  $2^{n+2}|(k^{2^n}-1)(k^{2^n}+1)$ but $2^{n+3} \nmid (k^{2^n}-1)(k^{2^n}+1)$** Then, the answer to your question is no, and that example provides a counter example.

This means that your question is equivalent to the following:

**Question** If $k$ is an odd integer and $n$ is a natural number so that $2^{n+2}|k^{2^{n+1}}-1$ does it follow that $2^{n+3} | k^{2^{n+1}}-1$?

I suspect that the answer is no, and a counterexample can be found fast with a computer, but I could be wrong.

**P.S.** Doublecheck the powers over what you are trying to prove, are you sure that the obvious thing which was claimed was not (*).